# dynamic resource update not triggering re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to reproduce react-admin's example of [declaring resources at runtime](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#unplugging-the-admin-using-admincontext-and-adminui).  Once a user logs in, their authorized resources are fetched and stored in local storage.

I have added a custom method that just reads the authorized resources from local storage. I want to populate the resources based on this value. However, it seems that the `<Admin>` component is rendered before the user logs in, and, once the user logs in and the authorized resources update, the component is not re-rendered. The only way to get it to update is to refresh the page after logging in, which is less than ideal.

I have tried a myriad of different approaches, including `useEffect`, `useCallback`, etc. but I will leave my code as closest to the react-admin example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {AdminContext, AdminUI, Loading, localStorageStore, useAuthProvider} from 'react-admin';
import myAuthProvider from '../authProvider';
import myDataProvider from '../dataproviders/dataProvider';
import MyLoginPage from "./Login";
import i18nProvider from "../i18nProvider";
import Layout from "../Layout";

const store = localStorageStore();

function MyUI() {
    return (
        <AdminContext
            authProvider={myAuthProvider}
            dataProvider={myDataProvider}
            i18nProvider={myI18nProvider}
            store={myStore}>
            <AsyncResources />
        </AdminContext>
    );
}

function AsyncResources() {
    const authProvider = useAuthProvider();
    const [authorizedOrganizations, setAuthorizedOrganizations] = useState([] as string[]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAuthorizedOrganizations(authProvider.getAuthorizedOrgIds())
        // PROBLEM: This ^ is only firing once. How can I subscribe to changes?
    }, [])


    /*
     Every org needs to be defined as a resource, otherwise when we try to show an element from any org other than the first,
     react-admin does not find a route for it. However, we only want a single list view. So we declare all the other orgs
     as resources, but we hide them.
     */
    const hiddenResources = authorizedOrganizations.slice(1).map(buildHiddenResource)
    const visibleResources = authorizedOrganizations.slice(0, 1).map(buildResource)

    const allResources = [...visibleResources, ...hiddenResources]
    // After logging in, because there's no update, this ^ remains an empty array.
    // And because we use ready={Loading}, it looks like the UI is "stuck loading" forever after logging in =(

    return (
        <AdminUI
            loginPage={MyLoginPage}
            layout={Layout}
            requireAuth={true}
            ready={Loading}>

            { allResources }

        </AdminUI>
    );
}

// [...] definitions of buildResource, buildHiddenResource

export default MyUI
```

Note: My UI is based off of react-admin's [simple example](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/simple)

As for the auth provider:

```js
import {AuthProvider, fetchUtils} from 'react-admin';
import {getApiUrl} from "./environmentConfig";
import User from './User'

const httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;

const TOKEN_KEY = 'token'
const PROFILE_KEY = 'profile'
const AUTHORIZED_ORGS_KEY = 'authorizedOrganizations'

const authProvider: AuthProvider = {
    /**
     * Get a user's profile.  This is called login because react-admin expects the function that takes
     * credentials (normally username and password) and returns a result to be called login.
     *
     * @param token Access token.
     */
    login: ({ password: token }) => {
        const url = `${getApiUrl()}/accounts/profile`
        return httpClient(
            url,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` })
            })
            .then(({ json }) => {
                const parsedJson = json as User
                console.debug(`Successfully logged in as ${parsedJson.username}`)
                localStorage.setItem(PROFILE_KEY, JSON.stringify(json))
                localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token)
            })
            .then(fetchAuthorizedOrgIds)
            .then(authorizedOrgIds => {
                localStorage.setItem(AUTHORIZED_ORGS_KEY, JSON.stringify(authorizedOrgIds))
                console.debug(`User is authorized for ${authorizedOrgIds.length} organization(s): ${authorizedOrgIds}`)
            })
    },
    logout: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY)
        localStorage.removeItem(PROFILE_KEY)
        localStorage.removeItem(AUTHORIZED_ORGS_KEY)
        return Promise.resolve()
    },
    // [...]
    getAuthorizedOrgIds: () => {
        let storedValue = localStorage.getItem(AUTHORIZED_ORGS_KEY)
        if (storedValue === null) {
            console.debug('Authorized organizations unset, falling back to empty array')
            storedValue = '[]'
        }

        const result = JSON.parse(storedValue) as string[]
        return result
    }
};

/**
 * Get the current access token.
 *
 * @return The access token, or null if none is present.
 */
function getAccessToken(): String|null {
    return localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)
}

/**
 * Make an API request to fetch the organizations that a user has access to in the API.
 *
 * @return A promise that resolves to an array of authorized organization IDs.
 */
function fetchAuthorizedOrgIds(): Promise<string[]> {
    const token = getAccessToken()
    if (token === null) {
        return Promise.reject('Not logged in')
    }

    const url = `${getApiUrl()}/accounts/authorized-organizations`
    return httpClient(
        url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` })
        })
        .then(({ json }) => json.data as string[])
}

export default authProvider
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you are missing a way to react to a change in the `OrgIds` stored in localStorage.

There are several ways you can fix this:

1. Wrap the localStorage in an abstraction layer that provides publish/subscribe abilities, so that you get notified when the values in localStorage changes. This is what react-admin does with its [`localStorageStore`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/store/localStorageStore.ts) for instance.
2. Wrap the call to `authProvider.getAuthorizedOrgIds()` in a query using [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/reference/useQuery), and invalidate the query after login to force a refetch of the data. You can have a look at the way [`usePermissions`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/auth/usePermissions.ts) is implemented for an example.
3. Probably the easiest solution: move your `getAuthorizedOrgIds` logic to [`getPermissions`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Permissions.html#user-permissions), and leverage react-admin's ability to [use a function as `<Admin>` child](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#using-a-function-as-admin-child).

Also, remember to also implement the permission checks server-side, because the localStorage is a client-side store, and can be altered by anyone knowing how to open the DevTools.

Hope this helps.